# Why is my JButton icon not showing correctly?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm currently working on some swing app.

When I try to make `JButton` to show just its Icon however it starts
 to overlap two JButton Icon's.

Does anyone have any idea what might have caused it  (I have one icon
 that says `'yes'`, the second says `'no'`,

if I move mouse over one button(let's say it is 'yes' button)  and
 then do it over the other (  'no' button in this case )
 `'yes'` gets painted over `'no'`.

*NOTE: Added the a solution to the code it is marked by comment*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class RunnerTestButtons {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame =new JFrame("Game");
    JPanel panel =new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0));
    JLabel label =new JLabel("SomeText",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    //here
    label.setOpaque(false);
    JPanel panel2 =new JPanel();
    //and here
    panel2.setOpaque(false);

    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(panel2);
    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));


    JButton lab1=new JButton("txt");
    JButton lab2=new JButton("Boo");
    lab1.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    lab2.setAlignmentX(Box.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    lab1.revalidate();
    lab2.revalidate();
    lab1.repaint();
    lab2.repaint();
    panel2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    panel2.add(lab1);
    panel2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    panel2.add(lab2);
    panel2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    lab1.setOpaque(false);
    lab2.setOpaque(false);

    lab1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    lab2.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    lab1.setBorderPainted(false);
    lab2.setBorderPainted(false);



    lab1.setBorder(null);
    lab2.setBorder(null);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: can you post little your tried code here ?

Comment: sure will edit in a second.

Comment: @vishalgajera: When editing post, please use `>` only to highlight quoted text. Please do not use it to highlight the original words of the OP.

Comment: @JakubRogacz please post code of mouse over event's

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. The code you posted is NOT related to the problem.

Comment: Well that is the whole code related to JButton I have.  I'm asking why it draws last moused over JButton on the currently "highlighted" JButton.

Comment: (1-) @JakubRogacz, I guess you don't want an answer. You have been asked to post more details, since the code you posted doesn't help. We don't know the context of how that code is used. If you don't want to make an effort to provide the information we need to solve the problem, then the question will go unresolved.

Comment: Ok but really what to post ? Nevermind just put up whole class there.

Comment: You where asked for a SSCCE and where given a link to explain what a SSCCE is. So basically all you need is a frame with two buttons. The code should compile so we can execute the code to see the behaviour you describe.

Comment: **Your solution to use the while loop is the completely wrong solution and should be removed immediately. Nobody should ever want to copy that solution.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lab1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

The problem is that you are trying to make the button transparent. You should NOT do this by playing with the opacity of the background.

For full transparency the easiest solution is to just make the button non-opaque.

So you should be doing something like:

```
//lab1.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
lab1.setOpaque(false);
lab1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information on why your original approach is a problem and the solutions when using partial transparency.

So as you can see the original code you posted had nothing to do with the problem, which is why a proper SSCCE should be posted with every question.

Comment: Corrected the code... but still pretty much same problem. It messes up  the two buttons and renders one over another

Comment: @JakubRogacz, Did you fix all the components where you are using transparency? Post your updated SSCCE. Again I can't guess what you are actually doing based on a verbal description.

Comment: Posted it. But I meanwhile found what was wrong. Generally you would need to call repaint from somewhere for the code to work good. It was an issue in the code I wrote because the loop must be outside the JFrame as if it is in it causes problems with events. Generally there must be a loop which will repaint JPanel for buttons to not get rendered over. It is quite uncanny because with filled Button it doesn't have any problems without repaint.

Comment: You did not fix the panel or the label. You should NOT have a color with 4 parameters anywhere in your code. No you do NOT need to invoke repaint() to have a Swing component repaint itself. **That while loop is the completely wrong solution and should NEVER be done.** Once you fix the background colors your problem will be solved. Did you even read the link I provided you???

Comment: OK I agree that having it not use colour with 4 arguments does help.

Comment: @JakubRogacz if this solved the problem, please mark it with the Green Check Mark. That's how we roll here :p

Comment: Thanks just started the whole bussines. Well i used before but not as an user